# I can ping all website except those controlled by Google

Tags: networking, ping

Normally I can ping and get a reply from google/youtube, but during high traffic periods in the country and when many devices are being used simultaneously at home,  I don't get a response. When this happens, all return timeouts.

This is the case for Yahoo and mostly all other websites.

```
gmail.com
google.com
google.co.za
youtube.com
```

What is going on?

All traffic goes through a single router (Single IP, using NAT). I'm using 8.8.8.8 as primary DNS.

Comment: This is extremely badly written. Do you mean that NORMALLY you CAN ping Google (that means yes and get a Reply). But when you are in certain situations (high traffic periods in the country / many devices being used at home), you cannot?

Comment: To one of the answerers (who now deleted what he write), most people **always** ping google e.g. www.google.com, and it's so reliable that they use it as a test that their DNS is working. Or pinging a google IP to test their Internet.  Pinging www.google.com [74.125.230.145] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.230.145: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=58     and -famously- pinging 8.8.8.8 (google's dns server)     Though if after pinging www.google.com and seeing the ip you do tracert on it you see it's something coutnry specific like lhr08s05-in-f17.1e100.net

Comment: @barlop correct, seems pretty self explanatory to me. What are you saying I must tracert instead...

Comment: I suppose you could see what happens when you tracert, maybe it'd show you the particular server that google.com is referring to that you can't reach.  Try pinging lhr08s05-in-f17.1e100.net  that is a google server.

Comment: Your problem wasn't written that well, it was saying you can ping(that can imply you get a reply), then it was saying you get timeouts , then later it was saying this only happens sometimes, (so usually you can ping and get a reply). I just stated your problem in the first paragraph including both the normal situation and the situation where it's not working, and I was clear about the meaning of can ping in the same sentence that I wrote it. So, I rearranged the wording to make it clearer like that.